# Como implementar a cláusula "where" como "in" e "not in" em c# Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Tenho as seguintes querys:

```
Select * from Processos where idProcesso in (1,2,3,4,5); 
Select * from Processos where idProcesso not in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Onde idProcesso é uma coluna com tipo de dado int.

Tenho também seguinte Código c# como linq:

```
public ICollection<Processo> ObterProcessos(List<int> lista)
        {  

            return context.Processos
                .Where(x => lista.Contains(x.Id))
                .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                .ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Na verdade não sei se a pergunta está clara para inferir que esta é a resposta, mas se naõ está clara seria fechada de qualquer forma até ficar.